# Adding Versioning to a table in Entity Framework (auto increment by group)

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, t-sql

I have a table "edits" like this:

```
id   group content
 1       1   hello
 2       1   Hello
 3       2   world
 4       2   World
```

I want to have a revision column so that I can see history on the edits to a group.

```
id   group content  revision
 1       1   hello         1
 2       1   Hello         2
 3       2   world         1
 4       2   World         2
```

so I would write something like

```
select id, group, content, revision
from edits
where group = 1
```

Though much more ideally:

```
_context.Edits.Where( x=> x.Group.Id == 1).ToList();
```

---

### My Question :

Is there away to make the revision auto-increment based on the group column?

**possible solution paths:**

The holy grail: a way to do this in OnModelCreating.

Not at all bad: a way to do this in ANSI SQL in the table creation.

Not too bad: a way to do this in TSQL in the table creation.

Less ideally: all sql reads require a group by, order by, rownum or something like that to simulate a revision number based on the natural ordering of the Ids.

Even less ideally: getting the last revision number from the Db. (I really hate this. Bad performance. Round trips +1)